# link subform to mainform access 2007

Tags: ms-access, database-design, subform

Mainform: has read only textboxes that reference a table (tblEmployee) that will hold flatfile upload data.

Subform: linked to "ID" field in tblEmployee table. Subform input data would input to tblEmployeeChangeover table. Subform is acting as an "update" tool. A user would look at the mainform, and if data needs to be updated, they would interact with the subform to do so. This is so tblEmployee is not modified, and the tblEmployeeChangeover can be used to email the new data only and also be used to run reports.

Both forms:

--have a field named ID, which is what they are supposed to be linked on. For example, if the flat file has ID of "3", then the subform should be "3" as well.

--Field names are identical for both main form and sub form, except subform has "_changeover" on them. So ID is ID for both forms. But "EmployeeSchedule" on Mainform is "EmployeeSchedule_changeover" on subform table and textboxes.

Problem: upload of flatfile seems to be fine. Need to be able to input data in subform that will be saved to tblEmployeeChangeover table. Whenever I try to input data into the subform and advance to a new record in the mainform:

-cannot input ID in ID textbox in subform

-which means data in subform is not linked to mainform textbox data

what do I do to get the subform to go to a "blank" form when the "next record" arrow is clicked on main form?

what do I do to make sure that the data is saved in the subform table when subform is updated?

If further info is needed, let me know.

Thanks,

PAT2B

Comment: Are you able to provide screenshots of the mainform/subform? If so, please include both Form View and Design View.

Comment: MJH, I apologize for the late response, but wanted to thank you for looking at this. The project scope has changed multiple times so the question I originally asked is no longer relevant. But thank you!